# Tool bar is scrolling (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, toolbar, statusbar

I have an issue. A toolbar in my app is scrolling when I open keyboard, or when I just scroll a toolbar. I have already tried to set color to status bar like somebody said on another question page on stackoverflow, but this didn't helped me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your xml and java code here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your xml code here, I assume that you have a ScrollView as parent containing a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout that contains your toolbar.

If I am right then simple solution is to put your toolbar outside the ScrollView.

Comment: No, my toolbar isn't inside Linear or Relative Layout. There is a screenshot https://postimg.org/image/ozg54264p/